# Add a UID to your GPG key, but don't make it primary

Tags: gnupg

Whenever you add a new UID to your keypair, GPG will automatically make it primary. Is there any way to add a key that isn't immediately marked as primary?

Although I could manually change the primary UID back to my originally selected one right after adding the alternate UID, I want to avoid creating extra self-signatures from where you change the primary UID back and forth.